# Searching for duplicates between all possible combinations of different 300 tables of names each in SQL

Tags: sql

The goal is to end up with a dataset of common names for intersection each table with another table.

This process has 44850 tables of results 300C2

(A, B ,C .....300)X(A, B ,C .....300)=(AxB , AxC ,AxD,........44850)

Comment: 19,900 tables?  Something is wrong with your data model.

Comment: thx i noticed it and i have change it

Answer (score 0):

If you have a number of tables, each with a column named 'whatever'
- Create a new table named 'tbl_names' with a column named 'unique_names'
- Now use [INSERT INTO](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp) 
to insert the 'whatever' column from each of your other tables
into tbl_names

```
INSERT INTO table2 (column1, column2, column3, ...)
SELECT column1, column2, column3, ...
FROM table1
WHERE condition;
```

- Once you have all the 'names' in a single table, including duplicates.
- Delete duplicate rows.
- [Here is a link](http://www.besttechtools.com/articles/article/sql-query-to-delete-duplicate-rows) showing how to do this.